# Excel Macro written in 1988 doesn't work in 2013

Tags: excel, macros, excel-2013, xlm, excel-4.0

I've been checking that macros that work in Excel 2010 still work in 2013.

The macro creator wrote all the code in a worksheet tab, assigns the code a name range, and then calls the name range as the macro.

The macro was originally written in 1998.

```
Named Range: Weekly Transfer(w)
=ACTIVATE("p&l")
=SELECT(!$A$2)
=ALERT("Macro to transfer weekly result onto year's sheet.  Is current week number in Cell A2? CANCEL to stop!",1)
=IF(A7=FALSE,GOTO($A$1))

=ACTIVATE("yr hist")
=SELECT("R2c7:c72")
=FORMULA.FIND(!$A$2,1,2,1,1,FALSE)
=SELECT("R[1]c")

=ACTIVATE("p&l")
=SELECT("R2c6:c10")
=FORMULA.FIND(!$A$2,1,2,1,1,FALSE)
=SELECT("r3:r290c")
=COPY()

=ACTIVATE("yr hist")
=PASTE.SPECIAL(3,1,FALSE,FALSE)
=SELECT("r4c")
=CLEAR()

=ACTIVATE("p&l")
=SELECT(!$A$2)

=RETURN()
```

The problem occurs at the 2nd `=FORMULA.FIND` command, it throws this error:

> We couldn't find what you were looking for. Click Options for more
>   ways to search.

The error occurs in 2013 but not 2010.

To make sense of the code above, you need to know that the cell `$A$1` contains `=RETURN()`.

Comment: I've never even seen this method before.. what is this called?

Comment: This looks like an old XL-4 or XLM macro. The code above is not VBA. I think you will have to translate it to VBA to make it compatible with newer Excel versions. There is a newer macro language called Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), introduced in 1995 in Excel version 5 (an application in Microsoft Office version 4.2.1). VBA is supported in all versions of Excel from Excel version 5 through Excel version 2016, with the notable exception of Excel 2008 for Mac which has no VBA support whatsoever.

Comment: And to mention: No there is no converter. You need to totally rewrite the code if you need to convert it to VBA which is highly recommended.

Comment: Excel 4.0 Macro Sheets are so old and unused that they don't even have a tag on SO. They were used before Excel had VBA http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/showthread.php?t=97331#post1862621

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies (and to my formatting angel) !!

We have determined that we will re-write all the macros that aren't working, and then start wading thru all the ones that do and convert them all. I've seen legacy code before but this takes the cake!

Comment: FYI: Excel 4.0 code is arcane and extremely limited but it will only take you a few days to get your head around it. There IS a benefit in upgrading from 2010 to 2013 ... I have timed all my macros and they all run faster on an Office 2013 machine (with the same hardware specs), and they also run faster in VBA than in the old macro format. Now, if there was only a converter to convert the code automatically....